# How to freeze header table in datagrid, using EasyUI + JQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the listing of orders this table is formed:

```html
<div class="datagrid-header">
 <div class="datagrid-header-inner" style="display: block;">
  <table class="datagrid-htable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 65px;">
   <tbody>
    <tr class="datagrid-header-row">
     <td field="calculation_id" class="">
```

This table is like a thead of table below. So oddly creating of grid table from jquery.easyui.js. I need to freeze this header table. Using frozenColumns as written in the manual does not work - becouse in the manual frozenColumns is applied to the usual type of table:

```html
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-options="field:'code'">Code</th>
            <th data-options="field:'name'">Name</th>
```

But what can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem using JQ:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 165) {
   $('.datagrid-header').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
   $('.datagrid-header').removeClass('fixed');
  }
 });
```

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed; top: 0;
}
```